# Three.js faces are rendered wrong with lathegeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I want to learn about webgl and three.js and I started pretty nice, but when I wanted to use this lathe geometry to create a circular health bar I got to see this: [example](http://dev.cgames.nl/digimon/public/three).
Please help me I'm in dire need for an explanation!

Comment: You need to be more specific on what you need explained. Can you post the relevant code that's causing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reversing the order of the points.